# list.reverse() -How to print reversed list of a string?

Tags: python, list, reverse

The user enters a word. The program must compare the words and inform you whether or not it is a palindrome. Here is what I have so far:

```
string = list((input("Enter a word: ")))
print (string)
x = string.reverse()
print(x)
if x == string:
    print "Your word is a palindrome"
else:
    print "Your word is not a palindrome"
```

From what I have read on stackoverflow, the List.reverse() only reverses the sequence in place and does not return it. Why can I not assign the reversed list to a variable and then print?

This is what it returns when I enter a palindrome:

```
Enter a word: 'ror'
['r', 'o', 'r']
None
Your word is not a palindrome
```

Comment: `reverse` reverses in place...

Comment: The reason your test always hits the else branch is that you are misusing the `list.reverse()` method. This method doesn't return a reversed list, it reverses the list in place and returns nothing. When you run `x = string.reverse()`, the list `string` has its order reversed, and `x` is set to `None`. But as Moinuddin Quadri points out, there are better ways to reverse a string than converting it to a list.

Comment: @Prune - that's not a duplicate. It's a recursive function with the error being that the recursive call isn't returned, while this question is a reassignment of an in-place operation becoming `None`.

Comment: reverse will reverse the calling list, but doesn't return anything which is why X is getting set to None.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: OOPS.  Wrong link.  I'll have to withdraw the closure vote.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to convert `string` to `list` and then reverse it.

You can simply reverse a string by doing `your_string[::-1]`. For example:

```
>>> x = 'abcdef'
>>> x[::-1]
'fedcba'
```

Save the reversed value with a variable and use that variable within your code.